# How to avoid a List in entity containing element before save but failing at persist time?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, bean-validation, bidirectional

I need to allow users to edit orders which include adding new order items and sub-items under those order items. I have modeled three entities accordingly, `Order`, `OrderItem`s and `OrderSubItem`s. Each `OrderItem` must have one or more `OrderSubItem`s (omitting additional entity props for brevity):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="[Order]")
@Data
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    @JoinColumn(name="orderId", nullable=false)
    @Valid
    @NotNull(message="order.orderItems.notNullorEmpty")
    @Size(min=1, message="order.orderItems.notNullorEmpty")
    private List<OrderItem> orderItems;
}

@Entity
@Data
public class OrderItem {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    @JoinColumn(name="orderId", nullable=false)
    @Valid
    @NotNull(message="order.orderSubItems.notNullorEmpty")
    @Size(min=1, message="order.orderSubItems.notNullorEmpty")
    private List<OrderSubItem> ordersSubItems;

    @ToString.Exclude
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="orderId", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Order order;

}

@Entity
@Data
public class OrderSubItem {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ToString.Exclude
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="orderId", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private OrderItem orderItem;

}
```

When a user request update of the order say to add a new `OrderItem` with new `OrderSubItem`s, the following controller is called:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/orders")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Validated
@Slf4j
public class OrderController {

    @NonNull
    private final OrderService orderService;

    @PutMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void update(@Valid @RequestBody Order order) {
        orderService.update(order);
    }
}
```

When the user sends:

```
Order(id=1, orderItems=[
    OrderItem(id=null, orderSubItems=[OrderSubItem(id=null, value=1)]), 
    OrderItem(id=1, orderSubItems=[OrderSubItem(id=1, value=2)])
```

validation passes here at the controller. Then, the service is called:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class OrderService {

    @Transactional
    public void update(Order order) {

        List<OrderItem> orderItems = order.getOrderItems();
        for (OrderItem orderItem : orderItems) {
            List<OrderSubItem> orderSubItems = orderItem.getOrderSubItems();
            List<OrderSubItem> newOrderSubItems = new ArrayList<OrderSubItem>();
            Collections.reverse(orderSubItems);
            for (OrderSubItem orderSubItem : orderSubItems) {

                if (orderSubItem.getValue() == null) {

                    //skip it                   
                } else {

                    orderSubItem.setIndex(newOrderSubItems.size());
                    newOrderSubItems.add(orderSubItem);

                }
            }
            orderItem.setOrderSubItems(newOrderSubItems);
            //also tried:
            // orderItem.getOrderSubItems().clear();
            // orderItem.getOrderSubItems().addAll(newOrderSubItems);
        }
        log.debug(order);   
        orderRepo.save(order);
}
```

Just before the save, I can see that every order item has a order sub item. But the save fails with a  `ConstraintViolationException` complaining that the newly added order item has null for its order sub items.

Why is validating failing? I think it may have something to do with the bi-directional relationship and the manipulation of the list.

**Update 1**

I created a custom `@NotNull` validator so I could examine the contents of `OrderItem` and lo and behold it `orderSubItems` is null during validation at persist time.

**Update 2**

After more research, I found that any `@OneToMany` property that I add to `OrderItem` will be null by only one an object that Hibernate appears to create. That's right, it appears that Hibernate creates an `OrderItem`. It doesn't matter if the relationship is bi-directional or not. It also doesn't matter if the list is manipulated or not. Other properties are populated fine. Now, here's the weird part:

**If I write a custom validator at the `Order` level to check that its `OrderItem`s have non-null `orderSubItems` and remove the `NotNull` annotation on `orderSubItems`, it passes validation and its saves without issue.**

That is, the `OrderItem` that Hibernate creates doesn't appear to be attached to the `Order` object. Is this an interim step that Hibernate does to save the `OrderItem` first, then get its id from the database so that it can save its `orderSubItems`? If so, why does it call validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes I prefer to use DTOs to customize and expose only fields that I need instead of exposing my entities to my API's clients. I think it's easier to handle entities when you have data in other objects.
For instance:

```
@Data
class OrderDTO {
    private Long orderId;
    private List<ItemDTO> items;
}

public void update(@Valid @RequestBody OrderDTO orderDTO) {
    Order order = repository.load(orderDTO.getId());
    for (OrderItem orderItem : order.getItems()) {
         repository.delete(orderItem);
    }
    order.getItems().clear();

    for (ItemDTO newItem : orderDTO.getItems()) {
        OrderItem orderItem = new OrderItem(newItem.getFieldA(), newItem.getFieldB());
        orderItem.setOrder(order);
        repository.save(orderItem);
        order.getItems().add(orderItem);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Danilo. I've got a better feel for the issue now. Your answer would probably ultimately get rid of the issue. So, I'm going to mark it as the accepted answer. I'll create a new question that addresses the "why" of the problem.